# A format of question with " For what"

Tags: questions

is this format of question correct and what is the alternative style?
For what this instrument is used?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: FWIW, in my experience, *For what...?* is very commonly heard in English spoken by Thais, when they really mean *Why...?* I very rarely here a Thai say "Why...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you say "For what this instrument is used" I would understand you, but I would think that English is not your native language.  More common would be: "What is this instrument used for?" or even "For what is this instrument used?"

When forming a question, we invert the subject and verb: "this instruent is" -> "is this instrument"

Comment: thanks a lot, and i am sorry for being late but. thanks again